# How do I #include <termios.h> in the Arduino Software (1.6.5)?

Tags: c, linux, arduino, termios

So this is what is happening now, I am using a code from URG Laser sensor and I am trying to compile it in the Arduino Software to see if it can be tested. However when I click "compile," this error message is shown:

```
In file included from /home/hadoop/sketchbook/libraries/urg/urg_connection.h:17:0,
                 from /home/hadoop/sketchbook/libraries/urg/urg_sensor.h:15,
                 from Laser_hpp.ino:4:
/home/hadoop/sketchbook/libraries/urg/urg_serial.h:22:21: fatal error: termios.h: No such file or directory
 #include <termios.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

I downloaded all the termios library I found for Ubuntu Linux, but it still gives me the error. The libraries I found I made a copy to where the urg_sensor.h file is, but it does not work as well.

I try to install via the command: sudo apt-get install libc6 or libc6-dev (termios library for linux), but they already are on their newest version.

So, I do not know what else to do. I really appreciate if anyone has any idea or comments about what should I do now.

Thank You!

Comment: Can you locate `termios.h` on your filesystem? Should be in the include directory. Run `find -name "termios.h"` if you can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

`termios.h` is not available in AVR Libc. You will need to port the code from Linux to the Arduino platform before you can attempt to compile it.